# How to run linux file on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 32-bit, executable, console

I have some proprietary command line tool for Linux, but not sure how to run it. There is no common extension like executable debian files. File info show `file file_name`:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=1e8f5c1fcec4949ff97cd55a4ac38f59d4188638, stripped
```

How to run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Just do `./file_name`?

Comment: I tried run `file_name help`, which should give usage info (as windows version have), but it just show `file_name: command not found`.

Comment: @muru Yeahh, sorry, it run this way!